# SQL for ordering by number

Tags: sql

I'm attempting to order by a number column in my database which has values 0-1000 and includes decimal numbers.

When I use

```
ORDER BY len([FY14 Points]), [FY14 Points]
```

I get...

```
0
48
150
249
36.9
39.7
44.5
52.5
54.4
57.9
58.4
60.1
```

I've also tried...

`ORDER BY registration_no * 1 ASC`

But get this...

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
>
> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '88.4' to data type int.

Does anyone know what I can do to get around this?

Comment: why would you use ORDER BY len([FY14 Points]), [FY14 Points] ? That's ordering the values on the length (number of characters) - I'm assuming you want these values ordered numerically?

Answer (score 0):

Change the data type of column [FY 14 POINTS] from varchar to int or decimal data type.

Answer (score 0):

Could try casting registration_no to decimal: ORDER BY CAST(registration_no as DECIMAL) * 1 ASC.  However, HBMirza's answer would be a much better approach.

The issue with ORDER BY len([FY14 Points]), [FY14 Points] is its ordering by the length of the value in the column.

Answer (score 0):

You have to first convert that to a decimal data type. You can try to_decimal for this. Then try to order based on it.

Answer (score 0):

Skyler,

SQL believes that you have set the datatype for `[FY14 Points]` to a `varchar`. This is what you will need to check into. When you sort numbers that are varchars it will be literally alphabetically sorted which is what you are seeing. THere are a few approaches. One would be in the `SELECT` Statment explicity select `FY14 Points` as a decimal or int, like this:

```
Select columna, columnb, columnc, cast([Fy14 Points] as int) from sometable
```

int can be replaced with any numeric datatype you want. The key point is that in order to sort this correctly it must be a number.